# Matrix inverse theorems

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure if this is a 'theorem' or not or if it can be explained by some other correct way, but can I 'take the inverse of both sides'?

For example $A^{-1}$ = B

So is saying that I'll 'take the inverse of both sides' correct? To get:

$(A^{-1})^{-1}$ = $B^{-1}$

And because an inverse of an inverse is just the matrix, I would get:

$A$ = $B^{-1}$

Is there any terminology or method that I've used wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Everything is correct but remember you can apply inversion on both sides only if you know at least one side is invertible (which is true in this case).

Comment: This is correct, provided $A$ and $B$ are square invertible matrices. Usually the statement "$A^{-1} = B$" means $AB = BA = \mathrm{Id}$. You need to be a little careful when $A$ is not square.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I get it now